# Fundamental Theorem of Contour Integration question (anti derivative)

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the definition of the fundamental theorem of contour integration that I have:

> If $f:D\subseteq\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function on a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $F:D\subseteq \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $F'=f$ on $D$, then for each contour $\gamma$ we have that:
>
> $\int_\gamma f(z) dz =F(z_1)-F(z_0)$
>
> where $\gamma[a,b]\rightarrow D$ with $\gamma(a)=Z_0$ and $\gamma(b)=Z_1$. $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.

I was reading an example that said:

Let $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ where $0\le t \le 2\pi$. We have that $\int_\gamma e^z dz=0$ by the fundamental theorem of contour integration.

---

The part I'm not sure is, how did they get that  $\int_\gamma e^z dz=0$? I tried working it out myself and I got: $F'=e^z=f$. Also, $F(z)=e^z$

$F(z_1)=F(\gamma(b))=F(\gamma(2\pi))=F(e^{2\pi i})=e^{e^{2\pi i}}\\
F(z_0)=F(\gamma(a))=F(\gamma(0))=F(1)=e^1$.

But how does $\int_\gamma e^z dz =F(z_1)-F(z_0) = e^{e^{2\pi i}} - e^1 =0 $?

Comment: $e^{2\pi i} = e^0(\cos2\pi + i\sin2\pi) =  \cos 0 + i\sin 0 = 1 + 0 = 1$, right?

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks. I forgot about euler's formula!

Comment: Note that your curve is the unit circle, so in particular it is *closed*, i.e $\gamma(2\pi) = \gamma(0) = 1$. This curve will return over and over and you need to learn to recognize it.

Comment: Thanks @mrf , may I ask, is $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ the half unit circle or the full unit circle? In my notes (might have written wrongly, there was a picture of a half unit circle)?

Comment: That depends on the interval. Note that $e^{it} = \cos t + i\sin t$, so the point $e^{it}$ is the point on the unit circle for which the angle (counting from the positive $x$-axis) is $t$. To trace out the complete circle, let $t$ vary from $0$ to $2\pi$. To get the semi-circle in the upper half plane, let $t$ vary from $0$ to $\pi$. Try to figure out a few other variations on your own.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks for your help again! Also, if I have $\gamma(t)=Re^{it}$ for $R\in \mathbb{R}$, is $R$ the radius of the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, assuming that $R > 0$. If $R < 0$, the radius is $-R$. (But you wouldn't call this a *unit* circle.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help again. Yes, I do think visualising these contour integrals geometrically would help alot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why $\int_\gamma e^z=0$ was explained in comments by *mrf*:

1. $\gamma$ is a closed curve because $\gamma(2\pi)=1=\gamma(0)$
2. the function $e^z$ has an antiderivative, namely $e^z$ itself.

It is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus (contour integration version) that every function with an antiderivative in some region $\Omega$ integrates to zero over every  closed curve contained in $\Omega$.